# Authorization dbo maps to a user with an old machine name

Tags: sql-server, users, sql-server-2017, authorization

I am trying to run a command that looks like this:

```
Create ASSEMBLY [AssemblyName]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
From ...
```

When this runs, it returns an error message: `Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'oldMachineName\username', error code 0x534`.

In this case `oldMachineName` is the old machine name for my computer. I changed the computer's machine name to `newMachineName` before every installing Sql Server, but there are obviously some vestiges of it hanging around.

When I log into Sql Server using SSMS, it correctly lists the logged-in user as `newMachineName\username`. Yet when running this command with `Authorization dbo` it is trying to use `oldMachineName`.

So, how can I convince Sql Server that `oldMachineName` doesn't exist anymore and teach it the correct group/user of the current dbo (ie: my logged in user)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the database was created/restored/attached by a Windows account user that no longer exists. Change the database owner to a valid existing login using `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::YourDatabase TO SomeValidLogin;
```

Consider creating a login, perhaps one per database, without `CONNECT` permissions for database ownership purposes. That will avoid this sort of problem going forward.

Comment: The database was created yesterday, I have not used the oldMachineName account since the first time I logged into the computer two years ago and changed the machine name.

Comment: Regarding the machine name change, what does `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` return?

Comment: It returns my current machine name (newMachineName)

Comment: Do you get the error if you turn off the `clr strict security` config option?

Comment: It works when I turn off `clr strict security`

Comment: @YaakovEllis, I'll need to do some research to find where the artifact of the old machine name exists that affects the new CLR security model but I I'm off to my day job right now.

Comment: @YaakovEllis, please join [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72323/chat-for-question-https-dba-stackexchange-com-questions-196223-authorization-db) to continue the discussion.